# Macro to copy one range to another, as values and as formulas

Tags: vba, excel

Please advise on the code required to fill this description:

I need to create a macro to copy the range L18:L20 and paste the formulas in the corresponding column (M18:M20). I then need to use paste special and copy and paste the values from range M18:M20 in the range L18:L20.

I then need this to sort of loop so when I run the macro the formulas from M18:M20 get copied and pasted in N18:N20 and then the copy and paste values from N18:N20 to M18:M20 and so on.

Here is my code :

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("L18:L20").Copy
Range("M18:M20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
                            Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, _
                            Transpose:=False
Range("M18:M20").Copy
Range("L18:L20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                            Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=False, _
                            Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: smells like homework show us your code :)

Comment: Do these actions manually while recording a macro: http://www.excelfunctions.net/Record-A-Macro.html Then, afterwards, edit the generated code to finetune it and make it more generic. Assign to button and presto.

Comment: @steenbergh Yes, I am a newbie at vba and macros. I did it using the recorder and I can assign it to a button, however I cannot seem to create the loop where it will shift to the column with the latest range (now holding the formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try :

```
Sub test_Andrew()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    LastCol As Integer

Set Ws = ActiveSheet

With Ws
    LastCol = .Cells(18, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Range(.Cells(18, LastCol), .Cells(20, LastCol)).Copy
    .Cells(18, LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                Transpose:=False
    .Range(.Cells(18, LastCol + 1), .Cells(20, LastCol + 1)).Copy
    .Cells(18, LastCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, _
                                SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                Transpose:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Andrew : Glad I could help! ;) **As you are new to SO, just a few pointers** : When your **problem is solved, you can validate the answer by clicking in the tick** right under the up/down vote arrows. **Use up/down votes on each posts(Q or A) that you find useful/useless(or bad quality)**. And take a look at the links to know how to ask proper questions : stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1(colindex As Integer)
    ' ' Macro1 Macro '
    'make our ranges variable and based on the input column
    Dim range_alpha As Range, range_beta As Range
    Set range_alpha = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(18, colindex), ActiveSheet.Cells(20, colindex))
    Set range_beta = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(18, colindex + 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(20, colindex + 1))
    range_alpha.Select

    range_alpha.Select
    Selection.Copy
    range_beta.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    range_beta.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    range_alpha.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("M18:M20").Select
End Sub


Sub Macro1_BySelection()
    '' use this sub to call Macro 1 if you want to select a column first
    Macro1 Selection.Column
End Sub


Sub Macro1_ByProbe()
    '' use this sub to call Macro 1 for the first empty column found
    Dim tst As String
    Dim colindex As Integer
    colindex = 1
    tst = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, colindex).Value

    Do While tst <> ""
        colindex = colindex + 1
        tst = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, colindex).Value
    Loop

    Macro1 colindex
End Sub
Sub Macro1_ByR3uk()
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Macro1 LastCol + 1
End Sub
```

Your initial function has been tweaked to act not on the fixed range of "Lxx" but to accept a number as column index.

The two other macro's offer two distinct ways of determining which range to use:

- `Macro1_BySelection()` uses the cell that is selected when the macro is called.
- `Macro1_ByProbe()` tests to find the first empty column.
- EDIT: I liked R3uk's way of finding the last used column better than mine, used his technique for `macro1_ByR3uk()` (we learn every day :-) )

Comment: @Andrew No problem; I've even learned something myself figuring this out. If this answer has solved your question please consider  [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both you and me.

Comment: I tried clicking on the tick but it only allows me to tick one answer and not both (as I first accepted R3uK answer). Please advise on this